# GWT Chart.js implementation throws 'unable to get property 'insertBefore' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, java, gwt, html5-canvas, chart.js

I'm trying to integrate the Chart.js charts (http://www.chartjs.org) in a current GWT project.  I have the project recognizing the javaScript but when I attempt to instantiate a Chart, my browser throws the following JavaScript error:

> Unable to get property 'insertBefore' of undefined or null reference

Using the following GWT code snippet that seems to be the root of the problem:

```
    Public class PieChart implements IsWidget
    {
        Canvas c;
        public JavaScriptObject jsChart;

        public PieChart()
        {
           c = Canvas.createIfSupported();

           if (c.getContext2d().getCanvas().getParentNode() == null)
           {
              //Debug message here
           }

           jsChart = init(c.getContext2d());
        }

        private native JavaScriptObject init(Context2d ctx)
        /*-{
              var data = [];
              return new $wnd.Chart(ctx).Pie(data);  //<-- *Explodes here*
        }-*/;

        @Override
        public Widget asWidget() { return c; }
    }
```

An instance of this PieChart class is created and added to a VerticalPanel during client creation.

The null debugging check condition reveals that the parentNode is indeed null and digging into the JavaScript reveals a call to 'parentNode.insertBefore' during the creation of the Chart object - so naturally it fails.

A null check of the Canvas c reveals a valid object, yet no parentNode so to my mind, there is either something wrong with my html document such that the Canvas is the topmost object or there is a configuration issue with my project overall that causes the call to the Canvas creation method to return a poorly constructed instance.

Is there a way to artificially bury my created Canvas one level down so that the parentNode won't be null (Or something like that)?  Or am I missing a step somewhere?

Here's the HTML of my page:

```
    <!doctype html>
       <html>
          <head>
             <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
             <link type="text/css" rel="sytlesheet" href="viewer.css">
             <title>Viewer</title>
             <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="viewer/moment.js"></script>
             <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="viewer/Chart.js"></script>
             <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="viewer/viewer.nocache.js"></script>
          </head>

          <body>
             <noscript>
                   ...
             </noscript>
          </body>
       </html>
```

The project cannot be hosted on public internet, hence the need for an offline solution like Chart.js

I'm also open to alternative offline charting packages that play well with GWT.  However, the alternative must be licensed as open source or otherwise freely distributable commercially worldwide for ITAR export compliance.

Thanks folks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private native JavaScriptObject init(Context2d ctx)
    /*-{
          var data = [];
          return $wnd.Chart(e).Pie(data);  //<-- *Explodes here*
    }-*/;
```

What is `e`? Is it allowed to be undefined at this point when you pass it to the chart?

From just a very quick glance at the linked project, you should be creating that `Chart` with `new`, and you should be passing the canvas Context2d instance `ctx` into it instead of this unknown `e`.

It is also very likely due to how canvas works that this will not behave correctly if your canvas is not attached to the dom, and your `PieChart` constructor doesn't attach it before it invokes `init`. If that is a requirement, you likely need to not invoke `init` until the widget's attach event goes off or `onAttach` is called, but you should learn more about how to wrap this project.

---

There are GWT compatible chart libraries out there, including Lienzo, GXT, and Highcharts. Full disclosure, I worked with Sencha building GXT for several years, and so have an obvious preference there.

Comment: Sorry - fat fingered the transcript of this code.  e == ctx here.  I'll edit the OP.  Re: other chart prefs - Appreciate the alternatives.  I will check those out to be sure.  I'll reply again when I've implemented those changes.

Comment: Based on your reply, I took a closer look at the timing of all the initializations happening when the client connects to the server and it seems to be precisely what you mentioned - the DOM objects have not had a chance to properly instantiate before I tried to reference them.  My fix was to call the init() function after the created PieChart object was attached to the its panel.  The chart doesn't appear, but that's a different problem.  At least my parentNode is now valid.  :)  Thanks!